# GASで以下の構文でbigqueryたたきたいのですが、なぜがクエリを呼び込めません。

Tags: google-apps-script

何故クエリを呼び出せないかわかりません。
ちなみに、シンプルたたくことはできるので、連携上は問題ないです。

```
function get_data(sql,sql_result) {
  var projectNumber = 'XXX';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(ss.getName());


  var result_sheet = sql_result; 
  function onOpen() {
    var menus = [{name:'実行',functionName:'onRunQuery'}];
    ss.addMenu('BigQuery',menus);
  }

  function onRunQuery() {

    var del_col = result_sheet.getLastColumn();
    var del_row = result_sheet.getLastRow();
    result_sheet.getRange('A1','A1',del_row,del_col).clear();
    result_sheet.getRange('A1','A1',del_row,del_col).clearFormat();
    result_sheet.getRange('A1','A1',del_row,del_col).clearDataValidations();


    var query_results;
    var resource = {
      query : sql,
      timeoutMs: 1000000
    };

    try {
      query_results = BigQuery.Jobs.query(resource, projectNumber);
    }
    catch (err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      Browser.msgBox(err);
      return;
    }
    while (query_results.getJobComplete() == false) {
      try {
        query_results = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectNumber, queryResults.getJobReference().getJobId());
        if (query_results.getJobComplete() == false) {
          Utilities.sleep(3000);
        }
      }
      catch (err) {
        Logger.log(err);
        Browser.msgBox(err);
        return;
      }
    }

    var resultCount = query_results.getTotalRows();
    var resultSchema = query_results.getSchema();

    var resultValues = new Array(resultCount);
    var tableRows = query_results.getRows();

    for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
      var cols = tableRows[i].getF();
      resultValues[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        resultValues[i][j] = cols[j].getV();
      }
    }
    result_sheet.getRange(start_row,start_column,resultCount,tableRows[0].getF().length).setValues(resultValues).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);
  }
}
```

Comment: クエリの実行を try catch で囲んでいますが、何らかのエラーメッセージが表示されていますか？

Comment: いえエラーは表示されません。

Comment: 例えばクエリの内容が SELECT 文だとして、result set が 0 件という状況も考えられますが、具体的にはどの様なクエリなのでしょう？

Comment: カラムに貼られているクエリは、実際ビッククエリ上では値を返却するので、クエリ事態には問題ないかと思います。

Comment: 上記のGASで、ビッククエリにリクエスト飛ばないのは、何か構文ミスがあると思っていたのですが、それ以外を探ったほうがよさそうでしょうか

Comment: その判断がつきませんでした。すみません。

Comment: 念の為、`get_data(sql, sql_result)` として渡している `sql` と `sql_result` の内容を確認してみてはどうでしょうか。